# How to get know own contact while fetching Address book Iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, abaddressbook

In my app i show the contact list by fetching address book in a Table View.I want to show a 'Me' Label in front of My Contact name which have my own no.like iphone native app.

How to get know it while fetching address book

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get it. It's assumed Apple did this as a privacy measure.